# Speed up MySQLi queries having different params

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli

A particular web page usually executes same query every time with different parameters.
For example suppose a registration page:
This page executes same query with different parameters of name, address, city etc

I am new to mysqli but I've heard that each mysqli query that is to be executed is compiled by the server and then executed.

Is it possible to pre-compile the query on that page so that each time different users load the page he just has to pass parameters to pre-compiled query and the query is not parsed again an again.

My Objective is just to speed up operations.

Answer (score 0):

You heard it wrong.

1. There is not much use for precompiled queries as such a compilation is blazingly fast already.
2. There is no way to make it anyway for your registration page.

> My Objective is just to speed up operations.

This objective deserves a distinct note.
Please, do not make objectives out of nowhere. For example, try to speed up operations only if these operations indeed require any improvements. Otherwise you either just waste your time or make things even worse.